# When you go out in Tichu, does the current round continue?

Tags: tichu

Pretend 10-10 is played and then I go out with J-J. Does the current round continue (players playing Q-Q or higher, etc), hence I would not claim the cards, or does it end (me still obviously being out) and the next player will lead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The current round continues and someone else can win the trick, unless you're the third player to go out, in which a new round begins.

Answer (score 2):

As Lobsang mentioned: yes, the round continues.

If everybody passes, you (player of J-J) would take the trick, then cede the lead of the next hand to the player next in order, since you have nothing left to play.